Проблема с работой QLineEdit
И снова я. На этот раз не получается осуществить проверку в модуле pl() через метод QLineEdit. Какое бы значение я ни вводил, верного ответа не получаю.
Допустим если выводится В конце каждого дня, когда солнце ушло за горизонт, я прихожу в свое уютное убежище. Здесь, мягкий уголок, где я могу полностью расслабиться и забыть обо всех заботах. Где так люблю сидеть за копьютером, в окружении мягких подушек, на ничем не прикрытой простыне., то при вводе в строку a должен выдоваться ответ в консоли Верно, они поставлены у кровати, но ничего не получается, а лишь меняется рандомное значение key и всё. До этой функции, в функциях OkEdit() и slippers() всё получается корректно. Перепробовал много чего, но так и не получилось.
Если появились какие либо вопросы на счёт кода или чего либо ещё, то пишите, отвечу в силу своих знаний.
Буду признателен, если поможете.
import sys from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap import random as rd import AllText as at import free_zone_disin as fr

place = {
    "a": 'Поставлены у кровати',
    "b": 'Оставлены у входа',
    "c": 'Брошены за дверью',            
    "j": 'Остались под столом',
    "k": 'Спрятались за шторой',
    "l": 'Убежали из комнаты'
    }
zero = place["a"]
one = place["b"]
two = place["c"]
three = place["j"]
four = place["k"]
five = place["l"]
occuped_place = zero
Place_1 = " В конце каждого дня, когда солнце ушло за горизонт, я прихожу в свое уютное убежище. Здесь, мягкий уголок, где я могу полностью расслабиться и забыть обо всех заботах. Где так люблю сидеть за копьютером, в окружении мягких подушек, на ничем не прикрытой простыне.  "

place_2 = " 'Эх, похоже после учёбы вновь не переобулся и они остались тамже, где и утром, перед уходом. Не хорошо, надо их принести, но блин, так не хочется вновь вставать с уже тёплой постели.' Мямлил я про себя, уже подымаясь с нагретого местечка "

place_3 = " 'Чёрт, да где же они? А что тут делает мусорный мешок? я же его выносил сегодня днём... Чёрт, похоже я опять перепутал и выставил за дверь не то.' Вылазя из-за стола, почуяв холод в ногах."

place_4 = " 'Моё любимое рабочее место, больше похожее на школьную парту, но именно там ко мне приходят самые лучшие мысли' Подумал я, окинув взглядом комнатку, в поисках своих тапочек "

place_5 = " 'Почему их вновь нет на своём месте?' В который раз я задаю этот вопрос, словно сам себе, когда прихожу домой. Но ответ мне всегда известен, он всегда один и тотже: после моих посиделок на подокойнике, за просмотром за холодным дождём, омывающим серый город и проходящих снизу людей, они забываются под ним, закрытые плотной тканью.  "

place_6 = " 'Я их выбросил, и нужно было купить новые...' Уже какой день сижу на кровати с этими мыслями, неотрывно смотря на скопище всякого хлама на полках напротив меня, и чувствую, что мои ноги становятся всё хололнее и холоднее. "

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        #MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(snow_bus_pixel_03.png);\n background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Main_enter = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Main_enter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(255, 530, 300, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.Main_enter.setFont(font)
        self.Main_enter.setObjectName('Main_enter')
        self.Main_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.Main_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(557, 530, 60, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.Main_btn.setFont(font)
        self.Main_btn.setObjectName("Main_btn")
        self.Main_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.Main_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 720, 460))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Main_text.setFont(font)
        self.Main_text.setObjectName("Main_text")
        self.Main_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.Main_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(295, 20, 400, 30 ))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.Main_label.setFont(font)
        self.Main_label.setObjectName("Main_label")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 400, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label1.setFont(font)
        self.label1.setObjectName('Label1')
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 400, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label2.setFont(font)
        self.label2.setObjectName('Label2')
        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label3.setGeometry(30, 160, 500, 30)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label3.setFont(font)
        self.label3.setObjectName("Label3")
        self.End_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.End_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(255, 500, 300, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.End_label.setFont(font)
        self.End_label.setObjectName("End_label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.add_function()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Main_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбор программы"))
        self.Main_enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.Main_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ок"))
        self.Main_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Искать тапочки - 1"))
        self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбирать имя по его среднему значению букв - 2"))
        self.label3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RPG - 3"))
        self.End_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
    
    def add_function(self):
        self.Main_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.OkEdit(self.Main_enter.text()))
        
    def OkEdit(self, number):
            if number == "0":
                print('Программа завершена.')
                exit()
            elif number == "1":
                self.slippers(number="")
            elif number == "2":
                print('Программа №2')
            elif number == "3":
                print('Программа временно заброшена')

    def slippers(self, number):
        self.Main_label.setText("Программа №1")
        self.label1.clear();self.label2.clear();self.label3.clear();self.Main_enter.clear()
        self.Main_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.slippers(self.Main_enter.text()))
        self.label1.setText("Где твои тапочки?")
        if number == "какие возможны места?":
            self.label2.setText("Выберите место:")
            self.Main_text.setText("a: Поставлены у кровати\nb: Оставлены у входа\nc: Брошены за дверью\nj: Остались под столом\nk: Спрятались за шторой\nl: Убежали из комнаты")   
            self.Main_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pl(self.Main_enter.text()))
            self.pl(cry="")
            
            
    def pl(self, cry):    # Здесь осуществляется поис тапочек
            a = None
            b = None
            c = None
            j = None
            k = None
            l = None
            key = rd.choice(list(place.keys()))
            if key == "a":
                self.label1.setText(Place_1)
                a = occuped_place
            elif key == "b":
                self.label1.setText(place_2)
                b = occuped_place
            elif key == "c":
                self.label1.setText(place_3)
                c = occuped_place
            elif key == "j":
                self.label1.setText(place_4)
                j = occuped_place
            elif key == "k":
                self.label1.setText(place_5)
                k = occuped_place     
            elif key == "l":
                self.label1.setText(place_6)
                l = occuped_place        
            if cry == "стоп":
                print("Программа завершенна")
                exit()
            elif cry == "a":
                if a == occuped_place:
                    print('Верно, они поставлены у кровати ')            
            elif cry == "b":  
                if b == occuped_place:              
                    print('Верно, они оставлены у входа')                      
            elif cry == "c":  
                if c == occuped_place:              
                    print('Верно, они брошены за дверью')              
            elif cry == "j":
                if j == occuped_place:
                    print('Верно, они остались под столом')                    
            elif cry == "k": 
                if k == occuped_place:               
                    print('Верно, они спрятались за шторой')   
            elif cry == "l":
                if l == occuped_place:
                    print('Верно, они убежали из комнаты')             
             class Stert_prj(App):
    pass
     if __name__ == '__main__':  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow() ex = Stert_prj()  ex.setupUi(MainWindow)  MainWindow.show()  sys.exit(app.exec_())


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Gaspa, sorry, ваш код неподъемный. Попробуйте  посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA

S.Nick спасибо, ваши советы помогают. Я понимаю что мой код не очень хорошо, но я учу программирование не более 2 месяцев, а потому ещё тойко учусь оптимизировать его.  Но все списки находятся в отдельных файлах, а также все прочие функции я перенёс в новый класс.
